# CSMA-CD waits a random period of time before re-transmitting

Tags: ethernet

Theoretically we know CSMA-CD waits random period of time before re-transmit .
What is the main purpose of  this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is so that the hosts involved in the collision don't try to resend at exactly the same time and just have an infinite series of collisions, rendering the network unusable.

Comment: is there any disadvantage ?

Comment: Not really. It enforces hosts to take turns.